# How do I update useEffect hook when clicked on a button? (how to write the button submit method?)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, buttonclick

I am working on an API app that will return a list of jobs when user enter the job description or location. Initially, the page will return all jobs and display them to the screen at the first render (default useEffect). Now I want when the user clicks on the button, page will render a list of job based on user's inputs. How do I do that on my onSubmit function in order to update the value of useEffect hooks?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import SearchForm from './componenets/Form.js';
import JobLists from './componenets/JobLists'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]) //posts store a list of jobs
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('') //description of the job (user's input)
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('') //location of the job (user's input)

  //description input handle
  const handleDescriptionChange = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }
  
  //location input handle
  const handleLocationChange = (e) => {
    setLocation(e.target.value);
  }

  //submit button handle
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //once the user enter input and clicks on button, update the the useEffect hooks

  }

  //get data from github job API (fetching by description and location)
  const url = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${description}&location=${location}`
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}, [])

  return (
    <div>
    <SearchForm
        description={description}
        handleDescriptionChange={handleDescriptionChange}
        location={location}
        handleLocationChange={handleLocationChange}
        onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    {
        posts.map((job) => <JobLists job={job} key={job.id} />) //map through each job
    }
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-example-gm9o6

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import SearchForm from './componenets/Form.js'
import JobLists from './componenets/JobLists'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]) //posts store a list of jobs
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('') //description of the job (user's input)
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('') //location of the job (user's input)
  const url = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=${description}&location=${location}`

  const getPosts = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  //get data from github job API (fetching by description and location)
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  //description input handle
  const handleDescriptionChange = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value)
  }

  //location input handle
  const handleLocationChange = (e) => {
    setLocation(e.target.value)
  }

  //submit button handle
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //once the user enter input and clicks on button, update the the useEffect hooks
    getPosts()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchForm
        description={description}
        handleDescriptionChange={handleDescriptionChange}
        location={location}
        handleLocationChange={handleLocationChange}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      />
      {
        !!posts?.length &&
          posts.map((job) => <JobLists key={job.id} job={job} />) //map through each job
      }
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```